# Can give different color in CGContextSetRGBFillColor?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicolor

How can I give the color `HEXCOLOR(0xe3f3fbff)` in  `CGContextSetRGBFillColor`?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0xe3 / 255.0, 0xf3 / 255.0, 0xfb / 255.0, 0xff / 255.0);
```

Answer (score 3):

*CGContextSetRGBFillColor* requires *CGFloat* values for R,G,B and alpha (from 0.0 to 1.0), so you'll have to convert every component of the hex color to values between 0.0 and 1.0.

In your case:

```
// R = 0xe3 / 0xff = 0.890
// G = 0xf3 / 0xff = 0.953
// B = 0xfb / 0xff = 0.984
// A = 0xff / 0xff = 1.000

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context,0.89,0.953,0.984,1.0);
```

You can convert your hex color string to r,g,b,a values like this:

```
NSString  *color = @"0xe3f3fbff";

unsigned r,g,b,a;

[[NSScanner scannerWithString:[color substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2,2)]] scanHexInt:&r];
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:[color substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(4,2)]] scanHexInt:&g];
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:[color substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6,2)]] scanHexInt:&b];
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:[color substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(7,2)]] scanHexInt:&a];

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context,r/255.0,g/255.0,b/255.0,a/255.0);
```