# How to set a background color for the drawing canvas created with CGBitmapContextCreate()?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad, core-graphics

I assume that the background is transparent automatically if I use the device color space (RGBA, so with alpha). But I'm not sure.

How can I set the background color of my drawing canvas or bitmap context explicitely to make sure it is transparent when it is created?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135769/can-give-different-color-in-cgcontextsetrgbfillcolor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor ( c red green blue alpha -- )

USING: alien.c-types alien.syntax core-graphics.types ;
IN: core-graphics
FUNCTION: void CGContextSetRGBFillColor ( CGContextRef c, CGFloat red, CGFloat green, CGFloat blue,CGFloat alpha ) ;
```

see more: http://oss.infoscience.co.jp/factor/docs.factorcode.org/content/word-CGContextSetRGBFillColor,core-graphics.html

Answer (score 5):

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 0, 0, 1); //black color

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 0, 0, 0); //transparent color - alpha set to null
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work fine.

```
 // transparent
 CGContextSetRGBFillColor(cacheContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
 // image
 CGImageRef cgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"] CGImage];
 CGContextDrawImage(cacheContext, self.bounds, cgImage);
 CGContextFillRect(cacheContext, self.bounds);
```